# If the roots of the equation $ax^2-2bx+c=0$ are complex ,then find the number of real roots of the equation $4e^x+(a+c)^2(x^3+x)=4b^2x$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

If the roots of the equation $ax^2-2bx+c=0$ are imaginary,then find the number of real roots of the equation $4e^x+(a+c)^2(x^3+x)=4b^2x$.

The only information i'm able to interpret  is$-$

- Since the roots of $ax^2-2bx+c=0$ are imaginary,therefore $b^2<ac$.
- from the Descartes' rule $a,c<0$ and $b>0$

how to move further?

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ real? With "imaginary" do you really mean "pure imaginary" (i.e. real multiples of $i$) or "complex"?

Comment: @gammatester:Nothing is mentioned about the nature of $a,b,c$,for convenience  assume them all to be real.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are real and the roots are imaginary, then $b=0.$

Comment: @gammatester:How,will you please give the argument?

Comment: Well, from the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) you get $\Re(a/b) = 0.$

Comment: @gammatester:Are you concluding $b=0$ using dimensional analysis approach?

Comment: No, if a solution has real part zero, you have $-\frac{b}{2a}=0$ and therefore $b=0$ (assuming $a\ne 0$). Why should use dimensional analysis?

Answer (score 4):

If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers, then the function $f$ has exactly one real root, where
$$f(x):=4\,\exp(x)+(a+c)^2\,\left(x^3+x\right)-4b^2\,x\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
To show this, observe that
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=4\,\exp(x)+(a+c)^2\,\left(3x^2+1\right)-4b^2\\&>(a+c)^2-4b^2>(a+c)^2-4ac=(a-c)^2\geq0\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,,\end{align}$$
where we use $b^2<ac$ (from the fact that $a\,x^2-2b\,x+c=0$ has no real solutions).  This proves that $f$ cannot have more than one real root.  Because $f$ is continuous, as well as $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\,f(x)=+\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to-\infty}\,f(x)=-\infty\,,$$ we conclude that a real root must exists, whence it is the only one.

Comment: I have a doubt . You have shown $f'(x)>=0$ which means $f(x)$ is increasing and hence has at most 1 real root . But $f(0)=4$, so shouldn't the function have $0$ roots since it can not cut the x-axis ?

Comment: The function goes to negative infinity as $x\to-\infty$.  Note that $a+c$ cannot be zero and so $(a+c)^2(x^3+x)$ can get arbitrarily negatively large, but $4\,\exp(x)-4b^2$ is bounded from below.